# Turn a Counter dict object into something plottable by matplotlib

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I have the following code written that spits back the top words in news headlines from a group of different news sites:

```
... # list of headline words is in finale

filtered_word_list = finale[:] #make a copy of the word_list
for word in finale: # iterate over word_list
  if word in stopwords.words('english'):
   filtered_word_list.remove(word) # remove word from filtered_word_list if it is a stopword
filtlist = str(Counter(filtered_word_list))
line = re.sub('[!@#$-]', '', filtlist)
print(line)
```

When I try and plot this via:

```
plt.plot(line)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Counter({**BIG LONG LIST OF WORDS IT FOUND THAT WOULD MAKE THIS PAGE UNREADABLE**})
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py:215: Warning: Source ID 7 was not found when attempting to remove it
  GLib.source_remove(self._idle_event_id)
```

I have limited knowledge of how to properly use **`matplotlib`** (and the **`pyplot`** module in it) to know how to transform the Counter dict object that it spits out into a dict object that `matplotlib` could plot with `pyplot`.

Do any of you have any ideas on how I'd get started towards a solution to this?

Comment: I would recommend that you narrow down the testcase to input that fails to *`plot`*, and ask how to solve that issue. There is a lot of irrelevant code in your post right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `re.sub` without converting the `Counter` into a string, utilize `Counter.keys` for that.

In order to plot you can take `Counter` and dump it into a `pandas` DF.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

list = ["#hello", "@someguy","#hello", "@someguy"]

d = Counter(list)

key = d.keys()

df = pd.DataFrame(d,index=key)
df.drop(df.columns[1:], inplace=True)

df.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

If you keep `Counter` as a `collections.Counter` class it'll be easier to plot. The issue you're having is that you're trying to plot a `str`.

Comment: a plus 1 for actually answering the question

Comment: I'm **very** confident they're doing twitter sentiment analysis. Seeing `[!@#$-]` is a guaranteed indication. What they're also not realizing is that is they're tokenizing improperly that's why they're getting those special chars. But they didn't ask about that :/

Comment: Do those chars always appear at the start? If so you could str.strip them off

Comment: Seeing their edit it's news and reddit data, a little mistaken but close enough lol. I believe they do.

Comment: Could also `stop = stopwords.words('english');filtlist = Counter(word.strip("!@#$") for word in finale if word not in stop)` and avoid all the list copying and removing

Comment: Agreed, that would be much faster to remove them to prevent `Counter` from being executed on them

Comment: Thank you all so much for the help, especially PadraicCunningham for that time saving solution!  I think I'm a *bit* closer to figuring this out.. E: And thanks to @Leb for the solution in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the counter object into a list with `list(Counter...)`. You can get items, keys, values with `Counter(...).items()`, `keys()`, and `values()`. It is just a dictionary.

Comment: How  does address the OPs problem?

Comment: these are OP words "to know how to transform the Counter dict object that it spits out into a dict object that" Many people are confused initially by Counter object...

Comment: This is a comment at best and whoever upvoted is actually worse, you have not addressed the error, why the OP is using a regex or how to plot anything